# Last tweets within android activity

Tags: android

I'm fairly new to android development and need to create an android app where in the bottom half of the screen it will be in list view displaying the last 2 tweets of a user.

As I'm new to android and API's I've looked everywhere for an easy to follow tutorial but none really do what I need. Any ideas?

Kind Regards

Ben

Answer (score 2):

Twitter4j would be the way to go for such a query.

The lookupUsers(long[]) method will return info of upto a 100 people at once

```
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
ResponseList<User> userInfo = twitter.lookupUsers(new long[]{userId1, userId2, userId3});
for(User u: userInfo){
  System.out.println(u.getScreenName() + ": " + u.getStatus().getText());
}
```

Here's an in-depth tutorial for the same: http://www.java-tutorial.ch/framework/twitter-with-java-tutorial

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

You can use Twitter4j library.
This is the link: http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html

And this is a good tutorial made by O'Reilly 
http://www.creativelive.com/courses/developing-android-applications-java-part-1-partnership-oreilly